# Uncaught TypeError: guilds.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, discord.js

I'm pretty new to discord.js coding and have too it upon myself to  create a dashboard for my discord.js bot  but I've ran into this problem and I don't know how to fix it could anyone help me? If you want some other files I will add them! Code with error:

**MenuWrapper index.jsx**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
    
    
    export function MenuComponent( {
      guilds,
    }) {
        
        
    
        return (
            <div>
              {
                guilds.map((guild) => (
                    <div>
                       <li>{ guild.name }</li>
                       <Link to= { `/dashboard/${guild.id}` }>View Dashboard</Link>
                    </div>
                ))
              }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**How MenuComponent is used:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { getGuilds, getUserDetails } from '../../utils/api';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { MenuComponent } from '../../components';
import background from "./placeholder.png";

export function MenuPage( {

}) {
    
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [guilds, setGuilds] = React.useState( [] );
    let history = useNavigate();
    useEffect(() => {
        getUserDetails()
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data);
          setUser(data);
          setGuilds(data);
          
          setLoading(false);
          return getGuilds();
        }).then(({data}) => {

          console.log(data);
          setGuilds(data);
          

        }).catch((err) => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, [])

    return !loading && (
        <div>
          <h1>Menu Page</h1>
          <MenuComponent guilds={ guilds }/>
          
        </div>
    )
}
```

I would really appreciate any help because I've been trying to fix this for hours!

Comment: `guilds.map((guild) =>{ console.log(guild.name)}` tell me if you are getting a value

Comment: May you show how do you use MenuComponent component? It seems that you pass wrong props in it as according the error it seems that guilds is not an array

Comment: @debugger thats the problem when i try i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: guilds.map is not a function`

Comment: try : `guilds.cache.map()`

Comment: That gives the error: `index.jsx:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` I've also tried stuff like forEach but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
    
    
    export function MenuComponent( {
      guilds,
    }) {
        
        
    
        return (
            <div>
              {
                guilds && guilds.map((guild) => (
                    <div>
                       <li>{ guild.name }</li>
                       <Link to= { `/dashboard/${guild.id}` }>View Dashboard</Link>
                    </div>
                ))
              }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Can you try this

Comment: The servers are in the console but they do not get listed which I think is due to the error: `Uncaught TypeError: guilds.map is not a function

Comment: are you getting any error by trying above code ?

Comment: Yeah, `Uncaught TypeError: guilds.map is not a function`

Comment: whatever the value of guilds you are getting is not an array,  you can add more check like Array.isArray(guilds);

Comment: Thank you! adding that and a key seemed to fix it!